# Gradle: pass arguments to compiler from commandline

Tags: java, gradle, build, compiler-construction, command-line-arguments

`javac` command line options line '-AskipUses' take a class name as argument. Is there a way I can setup the gradle build to take a class name from command line and pass it as an argument to '-AskipUses' compiler option?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
def classNameParam = project.findProperty('AskipUses')
compileJava {
    if (classNameParam) options.compilerArgs << "-AskipUses=$classNameParam" 
}
```

Usage : `gradle -PAskipUses=classname task`

edit : enhanced with @lance-java's comment

Comment: Slight simplification `def classNameParam = project.findProperty('AskipUses')`. See [Project.findProperty(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#findProperty-java.lang.String-)